# What means the attribute return in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code like this:

```
[return: XmlElement("return", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false, DataType = "base64Binary")]
public byte[] WORK([XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.example.com/xml/someapi", DataType = "string", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)] string guid, [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.example.com/xml/someapi", DataType = "base64Binary", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)] byte[] data) {

   // some work
}
```

what does the attribute `return:` mean?

Answer (score 7):

I'd never come across it before, but it seems to be described as attribute targets in [Disabmbiguating Attribute Targets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3787ac0(v=vs.90).aspx)

> This sort of situation arises frequently when marshaling. To resolve
>   the ambiguity, C# has a set of default targets for each kind of
>   declaration, which can be overridden by explicitly specifying
>   attribute targets. C#

```
// default: applies to method 
[SomeAttr] 
int Method1() { return 0; } 

// applies to method 
[method: SomeAttr] 
int Method2() { return 0; } 

// applies to return value 
[return: SomeAttr] 
int Method3() { return 0; }
```

> Note that this is independent of the targets on which SomeAttr
>   is defined to be valid; that is, even if SomeAttr were defined to
>   apply only to return values, the return target would still have to be
>   specified. In other words, the compiler will not use AttributeUsage
>   information to resolve ambiguous attribute targets. For more
>   information, see AttributeUsage (C# Programming Guide). The syntax for
>   attribute targets is as follows: [target : attribute-list]

Comment: but the return will be and INT right? even if the return: someAttr, attribute exists.... what does the return: do?, can you explain it step by step on what is happening? I still don't understand how it works

Comment: I think the example provided in my quote above is a contrived one, but it stipulates that the attribute targets the return value of the method. So in your example above, my take is that it seems to indicate the return value is a `Nullable` `binaryBase64` `byte[]` that will likely be serialised as an XMLElement with no namespace. 
The takeaway here though, is that the attribute is to be attributed to the return value, and not the method itself.

Comment: it may return 3 type of values?

Comment: No. My interpretation is that it is a byte[] that is binaryBase64 encoded, but that it could be null as well. It is simply telling you all about the attributes of the return type.

Answer (score 1):

That is an [attribute target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/#attribute-targets).
It is decorating the attribute to make it apply to the return of the method, and not to the method that it is put on.

A more common use for this is the `[assembly:...]` attribute target, which is often used like:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyProject.UnitTests")]
```

## In detail

These are [Attribute Targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/#attribute-targets) that decorate attributes:

> The *target* of an attribute is the entity which the attribute applies to.

It is further explained:

> For example, an attribute may apply to a class, a particular method, or an entire assembly. By default, an attribute applies to the element that follows it. But you can also explicitly identify, for example, whether an attribute is applied to a method, or to its parameter, or to its return value.

The list of possible target values are shown in that document.

For example, the [System.Convert.ChangeType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype) method [is annotated like this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Convert.cs#L171):

```
[return: NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(value))]
public static object? ChangeType(object? value, TypeCode typeCode)
{
    return ChangeType(value, typeCode, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```